# How do I make syntax errors display on the screen instead of showing Error 500

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, syntax-error

This is what displays on my screen when I forget to add a `;` to the end of a function.

[image: syntax error]

This is what happens when I do the same thing online
[image: error 500 in google chrome]

How do I get the first effect on my website?

Comment: Can I suggest you don't have public facing errors? Instead read your error logs on your server. `tail -f /path/to/log.log`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP Errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Have you tried displaying errors with ini_set('display_errors', 1), though as previously mentioned, you should really check your logs.

Comment: I've tried the top rated answer by setting that and php.ini and it doesn't work. @JackNicholson It's better to show an error message than a error 500.

Comment: @desbest Not to the public. Read your logs on the server directly.

Comment: @JackNicholson Yes I get logs on the server but I want the log to appear on the web browser page too.